# Need some assitance with an update Script

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What I am trying to do is write some sql code to update a table based of the values in that table dependent of another tables value.

What I have is 2 tables 1)Name 2)CSAL

Name Table has 2 columns that I care about ID and CO_ID the ID is a key field and CO_ID shows is a record is a child of another record.

The CSAL table has the value of MunExpressConsent which can be 1 or 0

what I want to do is if the parent record has the value of 1 in the CASL table I want to update all records that has that ID as CO_ID in the name table to get the value of 1 in the field MunExpressConsent in the CSAL table.

I tried this but is not working:

```
UPDATE CASL
SET MunExpressConsent = 1
FROM TEST_AMO.dbo.CASL CASL, 
TEST_AMO.dbo.CASL CASL_1, TEST_AMO.dbo.Name Name, TEST_AMO.dbo.Name Name_1   
WHERE Name.CO_ID = Name_1.ID AND Name_1.ID = CASL.ID AND 
Name.ID = CASL_1.ID AND (Name_1.STATUS='a') AND (Name.STATUS='a') 
and Name.CO_ID = Name_1.ID
```

Thank for any assistance

Comment: Would you please clarify your statement: "...and CO_ID shows is a record is a child of another record"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and re-reading your question, I believe that you are looking to do the following:

```
UPDATE [CASL]
SET [MunExpressConsent] = 1
FROM [CASL]
INNER JOIN [Name]
    ON [CASL].[ID] = [Name].[ID]
WHERE [Name].[STATUS] = 'a'
AND [Name].[CO_ID] IN (
    SELECT parentName.[ID]
    FROM [Name] AS parentName
    INNER JOIN [CASL] AS parentCASL
        ON parentName.[ID] = parentCASL.[ID]
    WHERE parentName.[STATUS] = 'a'
    AND parentCASL.[MunExpressConsent] = 1
)
```

This will update all records in the `[CASL]` table that have a parent record with `[MunExpressConsent] = 1`.

<sub>**NOTE:** The parent-child relationship is assumed to be a self-reference within the `[Name]` table via the following relationship (pseudocode follows): `child record [CO_ID] column is equal to parent record [ID] column`.</sub>

Comment: I'm glad I could help. (In case you didn't know, the standard practice here on StackOverflow is to mark one answer as the "answer", so that future site visitors can benefit from this Q&A.)